# What to call a fitting that helps quickly release two PVC pipes?

Tags: plumbing, pvc, connectors

I have a hose that I need to attach to some PVC, but needs to be removable for maintenance. I found some threaded PVC ring, which I can glue to either side, that allows for it to be separated, the problem is there are so many threads, it requires 20-30 rotations, which means the hose needs to be twisted many times, and there isn't much space available for that. What is the name for a kind of fitting that allows for much quicker disconnect of PVC and PVC-sized plastic piping?

Comment: Is this just water, A chemical or a gas? There are quick disconnects that seal on both sides but the application would be needed to get the right type.

Comment: There are quite a few quick connects/disconnect around. Two pieces a male end and a female end.  Usually screw each end to each pipe/hose and then just need to push together to connect.  Types for garden hoses come in cheap plastic or brass and either treads or barbs ends to attach to hose/pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: union][1](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0424/2925/1744/products/4832_4833_360x.jpg?v=1594764356)

here is one union that I have used, and it works well. it's for a 3/4" dia. PVC- something you failed to mention in your question.  Of course, this attaches to PVC tubing on each end, but it might could be used in your situation with some additional fittings, depending on what kind of hose you're referring to. A garden hose with metal threaded ends?  what's dia. of hose and PVC involved? what's the application for the hose/PVC? IOW, how much pressure might be involved?

I don't know if it's "quick" but IIRC, it doesn't take as many turns as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

A "union" has parts that are fixed to the pipes on either side and a nut that's tightened in the middle to join the two sides without requiring either side to twist.

A set of garden hose thread adapters, especially where the female-threaded one is the swivel type, is another option. It is basically the same in concept as a union.

A "chicago fitting" is commonly used for joining hoses - air hoses in particular, but it's also suitable for water. It requires about 1/4 turn to join or separate.

There are also many "quick disconnect" fittings designed for garden hoses, pressure washers, and so on. These usually do not require any twisting of the pipes to join them. A web search for any of these terms will yield images and suppliers of the various parts.

Answer (score 0):

For a name would use push to connect or quick connect/disconnect.  Usually has treads to screw on, or barb to attach to a hose/pipe.  You mention PVC so guessing normal(not high pressure) water usage.  Garden hose suppliers should have what you need or if larger size, plumbing suppliers.